Javascript drawing feature not working on mobile
I need to be able to draw in a canvas using JavaScript.
I have the following code:
.JS
  function CursorSign() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var isDrawing = false;
    var lastX, lastY;

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    // Mouse events
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrawing);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrawing);

    // Touch events
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", startDrawingTouch, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", drawTouch, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stopDrawing, false);

    function startDrawing(e) {
        isDrawing = true;
        lastX = e.offsetX;
        lastY = e.offsetY;
    }

    function draw(e) {
        if (!isDrawing) return;
        var x = e.offsetX;
        var y = e.offsetY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    }

    function stopDrawing() {
        isDrawing = false;
        var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
        var base64Data = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, '');
        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = base64Data;
    }

    // Touch event functions
    function startDrawingTouch(e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        startDrawing({
            offsetX: touch.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            offsetY: touch.clientY - canvas.offsetTop
        });
    }

    function drawTouch(e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        draw({
            offsetX: touch.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            offsetY: touch.clientY - canvas.offsetTop
        });
    }
}

.ASPX

            <table border="1" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <canvas id="mycanvas" name="cnv"></canvas>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            

With the mouse cursor it works fine. But on mobile, like a tablet or a phone, it just moves the page around.
It also doesn't work on chrome's mobile version on the inspection console.
What other approach can I use?

mobile devices  famously have no "mouse" to move ... they are usually "touch" devices
